# how to make a batch file that edits a textfile

Tags: batch-file

i have a textfile for a program that is looking at my user profile name.
The rest of the path is the same.

is there a way for me to change the username using a batch?

Example:

C:\Users\user1\Pictures\background

is there a way for me to change the file path if im using the program from a different pc.

so that it says C:\Users\user2\Pictures\background in this path if i run the batch file?

Comment: Is this path the only item in the text file?

Comment: no but it is the only thing i need to change for hte program to work. If i do it manualy from any computer im trying from it works. So im thinking to: 
1 install the program
2 run bat file that changes the filename to the currentuser.

Comment: It matters because the solution often relies on the exact text in the file, so another line isn't changed also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do not hard-code absolute path and use `USERPROFILE` or `HOMEPATH` environment variables: they contains path for current user home directory (base path for documents and settings may be localized and it changes across Windows versions).

```
%USERPROFILE%Pictures\background
```

That said if it's just an administrative task then you may use a simple VBScript file to do search & replace (please note it's untested):

```
' Note we're reading backup copy (see batch file)
configurationFilePath = "c:\app\config.bak"

' Change this to proper value. Is it a hard-coded generic path?
textToFind = "C:\Users\user1\Pictures\background"

' From VBScript we're able to resolve MyPictures folder directly
Set so = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
textToReplace = objShell.SpecialFolders("MyPictures") & "\background"

' Loop through all lines of input file, output each line
' and replace old path with new one
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set inputStream = fso.OpenTextFile(configurationFilePath)
Do Until inputStream.AtEndOfStream
    text = inputStream.ReadLine
    If InStr(text, textToFind)> 0 Then
        text = Replace(text, textToFind, textToReplace)
    End If 

    WScript.Echo text 
Loop
```

All invoked from a batch file, first create a copy of your configuration:

```
ren c:\app\config.text c:\app\config.bak
```

Then invoke this script and redirect its output to (re)create configuration file with replaced text:

```
cscript updateconfig.vbs > c:\app\config.txt
```

Final note: please note that your program *may* even support environment variables expansion in path you specify in its configuration file. Try that before you write anything else.

Comment: That applies to a batch file but not usually to a configuration file used by a program.

Comment: @foxidrive yes, he tagged his question as "batch-file" then I supposed this is only issue he has (=he knows how to rewrite/update that text file)

Comment: @user17949 you welcome but don't forget to do a proper debugging, it's completely untested!